How to Access Custom Checkbox's IsChecked Property in .NET MAUI Using Appium?
I'm working on a UI automation test for a .NET MAUI application using Appium. I have created a custom checkbox in my MAUI application, and I'm trying to access its IsChecked property during my Appium test. However, I'm having trouble doing so.
I tried this but it didnt work :
var element =Driver.FindElement(By.Id("checkbox"));
var value= element.GetAttribute("IsChecked");

Appium1 is no longer supported. Are you using Appium1 or  Appium2?  Which platform do you want to apply Appium to? Android, iOS or Windows?

Did you set the AutomationId to the custom checkbox? For steps on using Appium to test Maui controls, you can refer to testing .NET MAUI apps using Appium.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT Yes I can Find the Checkbox but I cannot find IsChecked Attribute I use Appium2 and for iOS

When running UITests.iOS, do you get an error message?
